# OR rule in combination

Tags: probability, combinations

There are 10 cards with numbers 1 to 10 on them.
3 cards are drawn.

I think I know the answer for the first question and don't know it to the second question.

Q1: What is the probability of drawing 4,5,6 OR 5,6,7?

Say P(A) and P(B) are those above respectively.

From what I remember it should be like this:

- P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)
- P(A)= P(B)= C(10,3)/(10*9*8)=1/6
- P(A and B)=    C(10,4)/(10*9*8*7)=1/24
- P(A or B)= 1/6 + 1/6 - 1/24 = 7/24

if this is correct then I get stuck in the question below:

**Q2: What is the probability of drawing 4,5,6 OR 5,6,7 OR 6,7,8 OR 7,8,9?**
IT MAKES ME CONFUSED.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to draw them in that order, or do you just have to have those three cards in hand at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for Q1 is faulty. The most immediate mistake is that the probability of $P(A\text{ and }B)$ is clearly $0$, since you can't have both $4, 5, 6$ and at the same time $5, 6, 7$. You have only drawn three cards!

The problem is actually a lot easier than you make it. Assuming you don't care about the order in which you draw your cards, there are $C(10, 3) = 120$ different, equally probable $3$-card hands, and we want the probability that the hand we get is one of the two given hands. Using the standard formula $\frac{\text{Good}}{\text{Possible}}$ (the same one you use to figure out that the probability of getting a $6$ on one die is $\frac16$), the answer is $\frac2{120} = \frac1{60}$.

As for Q2, the exact same reasoning applies, and we get $\frac4{120} = \frac1{30}$.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you very much. So, just to make sure that I got it correctly I can say the probability of drawing 2,3 OR 3,4 OR 6,8 OR 8,9 OR 9,10 is calculated as 5/C(10,2) = 5/45 = 1/9. Correct?

Comment: @Yavar If you're drawing 2-card hands, yes.